# Alphabetical arrangement of 5 letters - MUSIC

Tags: permutations, combinations, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

"If you arrange the letters , U, S, M, I, C in dictionary order, in which position is the arrangement MUSIC"?

The answer I've worked out is 72 (working out below), but I just wanted to verify this with someone to see if my logic was correct!

**How I worked it out:**

There are 5! permutations of the letters. 24 of these start with the letter C, 24 with the letter I and 24 with the letter M (etc.)

So, already, there are 48 'words' before MUSIC.
Now we start listing the permutations starting with the letter C:

MCISU
MCIUS
MCSIU
MCSUI
MCUIS
MCUSI

and so on.

Thus there are also 6 arrangements starting with 'MI...' and six arrangements starting with 'MS...'.

So far, we're on 48+18 = 66 words

Now we start listing the arrangements starting 'MU...':

MUCIS
MUCSI
MUICS
MUISC
MUSCI
**MUSIC**

And so, we can see that 'MUSIC' is the 72nd word when the words are arranged in alphabetical order.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah this approach looks fine to me! I am not sure if this can be done using a faster method...

Comment: Thanks @AbhinavDhawan

Comment: In general you may work by recursion. As you stated, M is the third letter out of five, so there are at least (3-1)*4!=48 previous combinations. Now you have USIC: U is the fourth letter out of four, so you have to add (4-1)*3!=18 combinations; and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is correct but you could simplify this a bit -

Letters starting with either $C$ or $I$ or $M = 3 \times 4! = 72$

In $MUSIC$ - leaving $M$, all other letters are in perfect descending order so it has to be the last word starting with $M$ and hence it is in $72$nd position.

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover - that's a lot easier!!

Comment: you are welcome!